# Parte da String em Negrito, a partir de uma função

Tags: python, string, funções

desde já peço desculpas caso tenha respostas desse posts, mas as que eu encontrei não funcionaram nessa situação. Eu gostaria de saber se é possível deixar em negrito a palavra `"Lorem Ipsum"`, aonde ela faz parte de um bloco usando """, por exemplo. Se for possível, como funcionaria? Abaixo a função como exemplo.

```
def teste(x):
   if x == 1:
      texto = """
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   Has as been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
   """
return texto
```

Comment: Onde você exibirá essa string?

Comment: Eu estou utilizando o PySimpleGUI, a saída sairia na seguinte linha de código: win[' '].update(f'{texto}), caso precise de mais informações, me avise, eu atualizo o post com o código completo.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Use `"""\033[1m  Lorem Ipsum \033[0m`"""Acho que seria essa sua dúvida.

```
print ("""\033[1m  Lorem Ipsum \033[0m is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   Has as been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s""")
```

Comment: Ao fazer dessa forma ele devolve "None"

Comment: Eu estou utilizando o PySimpleGUI, a saída sairia na seguinte linha de código: win[' '].update(f'{texto}), caso precise de mais informações, me avise, eu atualizo o post com o código completo.